# create-react-app only creates package.json, package-lock.json and node_modules

Tags: create-react-app

This is my first react app.
I'm working on windows 10, node version **10.15.3**, npm version **6.4.1**.
This when i execute create-react-app command:

```
C:\Users\hp\Desktop>npx create-react-app app2
npx: installed 91 in 30.086s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\hp\Desktop\app2.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

+ react-dom@16.8.6
+ react@16.8.6
+ react-scripts@3.0.1
added 1404 packages from 727 contributors and audited 888973 packages in 
237.52s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

It just get stuck after this I waited for almost 20 minutes but nothing happened ,no success message or information about commands like npm start is displayed and I have to do ctrl+c to terminate the batch job.
The project folder created contains only package.json, package-lock.json and node_modules and package.json file does not have start,build,test and eject script
Can anyone please help me I am not getting what is wrong here

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am experiencing same issue... :(

Comment: I think the npm version which is downloaded with LTS version of node was the reason of this problem. Updating to the latest npm version solved the problem

Comment: Yes mine problem is solved too :).. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to update the npm package:

npm install -g npm

And then install create react app again:

npm install -g create-react-app

And create the project again

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it in three steps:

1. `npm uninstall -g crete-react-app`
2. `yarn global add create-react-app`
3. `yarn create react-app my-app`

It will work!